# Select2 autocomplete by option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have tried to integrate tag/autocomplete for my site. Its working through option text. I am almost close to result but still hanging.

Now when you try to select option text there will appear related text. But now i want to appear kathmandu or related option text searching via option value also.

Ex: 
when we will search value **a001** **kathmandu** will appear and select same as **a002** it will appear **pokhara**

```js
$("select").select2({
  tags: "true",
  placeholder: "Select an option",
  allowClear: true,
  width: '100%',
  createTag: function (params) {
    var term = $.trim(params.term);

    if (term === '') {
      return null;
    }

    return {
     id: term,
     text: term,
     value: true // add additional parameters
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="custom-select"  multiple="multiple">
  <option value="a001">Kathmandu</option>
  <option value="a002">Pokhara</option>
  <option value="a003">Lalitpur</option>
</select>
```

I think i am close after searching via value and click on it it will show relevant option with id. But i want only option text like **pokhara** **kathmandu** not an ID on select area.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove the double-ups of the `Id` and the `Text` showing when entering just the `Id` check whether the entered term matches an existing `Id`, and if it does simply return the `Text` of the matching option:

```js
options = [];

// create an array of select options for a lookup
$('.custom-select option').each(function(idx) {
    options.push({id: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
});


$("select").select2({
  tags: "true",
  placeholder: "Select an option",
  allowClear: true,
  width: '100%',
  createTag: function (params) {
    var term = $.trim(params.term);

    if (term === '') {
      return null;
    }
    
    // check whether the term matches an id
    var search = $.grep(options, function( n, i ) {
      return ( n.id === term || n.text === term); // check against id and text
    });
    
    // if a match is found replace the term with the options' text
    if (search.length) 
      term = search[0].text;
    else
      return null; // didn't match id or text value so don't add it to selection
    
    return {
     id: term,
     text: term,
     value: true // add additional parameters
    }
  }
});

$('select').on('select2:select', function (evt) {
  //console.log(evt);
  //return false;
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="custom-select"  multiple="multiple">
  <option value="a001">Kathmandu</option>
  <option value="a002">Pokhara</option>
  <option value="a003">Lalitpur</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I appreciate if disable to choose option except of list. Now its working via ID. Now can we avoid to select this tag http://prntscr.com/ept0yg

Comment: OK, that should be easy, it's just a matter of returning `null` when it doesn't match. I'll update the code...

Answer (score 1):

if you search `a001` then output is display id and text both in output. Learn [**placeholder**](https://select2.github.io/options-old.html#placeholder).

> If the value is an object, the object should be compatible with
>   Select2's internal objects. The id should be the id to look for when
>   determining if the placeholder should be displayed. The text should be
>   the placeholder to display when that option is selected.

Example : search `a001` after enter display **kathmandu**  and **a001** in **textbox**

**using** `placeholder` **in select2**

```
placeholder: {
        id: "-1",
        text: "Select an option",
      }
```

```js
$("select").select2({
  tags: "true",
  placeholder: {
    id: "-1",
    text: "Select an option",
  }, 
  allowClear: true,
  width: '100%',
  createTag: function(params) {
    var term = $.trim(params.term);

    if (term === '') {
      return null;
    }

    return {
      id: term,
      text: term,
      value: true // add additional parameters
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="custom-select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="a001">Kathmandu</option>
  <option value="a002">Pokhara</option>
  <option value="a003">Lalitpur</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes, but i don't need a001 on field. Just display kathmandu or lalitpur. Now showing both value and text