# Remove already selected value in jquery multiple autocomplete ajax

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How can I remove already selected value in a jQuery multiple autocomplete list?

For example, if I selected `word A`, next time it shouldn't appear in the list while typing. Also, if someone tries to remove an element using the backspace key that element should re-appear in the autocomplete list.

```js
$(function() {
  function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }

  $("#birds").on("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
      $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON("search.php", {
        term: extractLast(request.term)
      }, response);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var terms = split(this.value);
      terms.pop();
      terms.push(ui.item.value);
      terms.push("");
      this.value = terms.join(", ");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The simple way to solve this is on the server side. Send the list of already selected words in the AJAX request and exclude them from the response you generate there.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Selected words I am able to remove from server level but the issue is if the user manually remove any item from autocomplete by pressing backspace then how can I track it down so that I can send that particular item to server

Comment: You don't need to. Just send the value of the field in the request and split by the comma to form the array on the server. Then de-dupe the full list with those already selected.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How can I get the list of selected fields on backspace? I am not able to find any event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this does somewhat what you are wanting:

```js
$( function() {
    // Demo data -- store the data according to your need from database.
    let availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

  function getTermRemainder(str, p) {
let part1 = str.substring(0,p).split(',');
let part2 = str.substring(p).split(',');
let term = (part1.pop() + part2.shift()).trim();
part1 = part1.join(',').trim();
part2 = part2.join(',').trim();
let remainder = part1.length ? (
    part2.length ? part1 + ', ' + part2 : part1
  ) : (
    part2.length ? part2 : ''
  );
return {
    term: term,
    remainder: remainder
};
  }

    
  $("#birds")
  .autocomplete({
focus: function(e, ui) {
  return false;
},
source: function(request, response) {
    let start = this.element.get(0).selectionStart;
    let { term, remainder } = getTermRemainder(request.term, start);
    term = term.toLowerCase();
    let terms = remainder.split(',');
    let hash = {};
    for(let i = 0, l = terms.length; i < l; i++)
        hash[terms[i].trim()] = true;
    let matched = availableTags
    .filter(function(item) {
        return(
            item.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) !== -1 &&
            !hash[item]
        );
    });
    response(matched);
},
select: function(event, ui) {
  let selected = ui.item.value;
  let val = this.value;
  let pos = this.selectionStart;
  let start = pos;
  while(--start > 0) if(val.charAt(start) === ',') break;
  let end = pos-1;
  let l = val.length;
  while(++end < l) if(val.charAt(end) === ',') break;
  let result = '';
  if(start > 0) result += val.slice(0,start) + ', ';
  result += selected;
  if(end < l) result += val.slice(end);
  else result += ', ';
  this.value = result;
  return false;
}
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Tag programming languages: </label>
  <input id="birds" size="50">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I have made this snippet and it should work according to your need. I have taken the demo data from *jquery ui autocomplete site* https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/, so you'll have to replace the data from the database

```js
 $( function() {
    // Demo data -- store the data according to your need from database.
    let availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    
    // define a new variable so that the original variable is not affected.
    let new_availableTags = []; 
    
    // define a variable to store all the selected values.
    let selectedVal       = []; 

    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    // prevent the user from going behind via cursor //cursor always on last
    $( "#tags" ).on('click', (event) => {
      event.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(-1, -1);
    });

    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        
        // prevent from giving space(32), delete(46), going back(37) and forward(39), delete a whole word(Ctrl + Backspace(8))
        if(event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 8)){
         
          event.preventDefault();
        
        }else if(event.keyCode == 8){ // on pressing backspace
          
          let prev_val = event.currentTarget.value; //get the current input value
          let last_char = prev_val.charAt(prev_val.length-1); //get the last character of value
          
          if(last_char == ','){
            selectedVal.pop();  //delete last element only if last character is a comma(,)
          }
        }
        
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        //console.log(selectedVal);
        new_availableTags = availableTags;  //assign the value to the new variable
        
        selectedVal.forEach((selected) => {
            // only keep the values which are not selected
            new_availableTags = new_availableTags.filter(item => item != selected);
          });
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
          new_availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          
          selectedVal.push(ui.item.value);  // insert the selected value in selectedVal
          console.log(`selectedVal: ${selectedVal}`);
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
  <input id="tags" size="50">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to restrict user from backspace from anywhere in the autocomplete. Can you tell me how can we achieve it?

Comment: We are not restricting the user from using commonly used backspace rather we are restricting the user from deleting a complete word because then we won't be able to determine which word was deleted and hence, unable to show the deleted word again in the dropdown menu. :)

Comment: What if user selected from 10 words from autocomplete and he wants to delete the 2nd and 3rd word how can he do it? From your code he needs to delete all the elements till first

Comment: Yes, according to my code, he'll have to delete all the elements.

Comment: If you must do this then try select2 autocomplete-- <br> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967268/select2-autocomplete-by-option-value

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better if you store the `id` and the text too why not, whenever you make the `ajax` request pass these and handle them on the server-side.

```js
some_array = array();
$('[your-list]').keyup(function(e) {
  var text = $(this).text();
  // key backspace is released
  if(e.keyCode == 8)
    some_array.push(text);
});
```

Comment: When user will try to delete some elements from middle of the list. How to deal with it?

Comment: The event will trigger regardless of where the element of the list might be